# How to find out the block reward?

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc

I have node ETH. How to find out the block reward?
I looked at all the possible JSON RPC API requests.
But nowhere is there any information on the reward for the mined block.

Do I need to download all transactions from a block? Multiply gas by gasPrice and add from all transactions in the block?
Maybe there is a ready-made solution?
Ty.

Comment: reward and transaction fees are different things. Block reward is fixed to 2 ETH, https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d3e3a460ec947c9e1e963d1a35f887d95f23f99d/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L44 , no need in finding it out

Comment: yep, if you want to find profit from transaction fees then yes, you have to scan all transactions and multiply the values. it is going to be about 6 million dollars per day

Comment: or use dune analytics

Comment: @Nulik answer me on ur e-mail please